# Why Soft Link is Used in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

This question arose in my mind while I was installing JDK on Ubuntu. While I was installing JDK the steps are -

- Extracting the .bin file of java.
- Make a directory named java6 in /usr/lib and move all the content of extracted .bin file to the /usr/lib/java6.
- Now soft a soft link is created in the current directory like this-

  ```
  ln -s java6 java
  ```
- I am surprised that the newly created link 'java' is used to set "JAVA_HOME" environment variable. As far as I know a similar thing is not possible in Windows.
- More over while I am installing nexus I noticed the following -

  ```
  $ ln -s nexus-2.7-06-bundle nexus  
  $ cd nexus  
  $ ./bin/nexus console
  ```

What I am trying to say here is - first we access the link directory (nexus), then we are running script (in /bin/nexus). I noticed these two approaches in several tutorials. I think these approaches should have some benefits.

Now my questions are that -

1. Why a link (/usr/lib/java) is set as JAVA_HOME; what is the advantage of doing so?
2. Why we are running the script (... /bin/nexus) from going to the soft link directory and what is the advantage of doing so?

When I am using the base directory instead of the link for the mentioned two cases, it also works fine.  So, why these approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install java7 instead of java6 (or java7 parallel to java6
or something else like that), if the JAVA_HOME variable and 100 other things are set
explicitly to java6, you would have to change them all to java7.
(and it is not trivial to find all config stuff which need changes).
With the link, you set all config stuff to the link and change only the link if necessary.
And yes, this is possible on Windows too.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why a link (/usr/lib/java) is set as JAVA_HOME; what is the advantage of doing so?

- JAVA_HOME points to java you want to use (say java6)
- JAVA_HOME is just a convention, usually software like eclipse, maven etc... use it to find where Java is located.
- And yea it can be done in Windows too.

> 2) Why we are running the script (... /bin/nexus) from going to the soft link directory and what is the advantage of doing so?

- Advantage none (It depends on you how you see it)
- This Q is somewhat  similar to Q1..
- Say in future you want to use new version `nexus-2.8-*`. So instead of changing all configuration from `nexus-2.7-*` to `nexus-2.8-*`; you can just change the soft link `nexus`(to point the new version)

> 3) When I am using the base directory instead of the link for the mentioned two cases, it also works fine. So, why these approaches?

- You answered you own Q!
- Yep its a **link**; so `nexus` --> `nexus-2.7-06-bundle`; one and the same...
- why the approach? see 3rd point of previous Q

**Think of soft link as shortcut in Windows**